# Excel - find similar addresses in two columns and assign ID for each unique address

Tags: python, excel, vb.net, function

I have two columns A and B for a set of addresses. Similar addresses might exist in both columns. I need to remove duplicate addresses in both column A and B and assign an ID for each unique address. Then I need to return to the original list (with duplicates) and insert an additional two columns with those IDs. Example of original columns:-

```
Col A               Col B
----------        -----------
address 1a        address 2b
address 2b        address 7g
address 3c        address 1a 
address 4d        address 8h
address 5e        address 6f
address 6f        address 1a
                  address 9i
```

I need to remove the duplicates, so it will be something like this:-

```
Col A new          Col B new
----------        -----------
address 1a        
address 2b        address 7g
address 3c         
address 4d        address 8h
address 5e        
address 6f        address 9i
```

Then I need to assign IDs for each address

```
Col C unique address      Col D ID  
----------                ---------  
address 1a                P000001
address 2b                P000002
address 3c                P000003
address 4d                P000004
address 5e                P000005
address 6f                P000006
address 7g                P000007
address 8h                P000008
address 9i                P000009
```

Then go back to the original columns and add these IDs to each address, as shown below:-

```
Col A           Col AID           Col B              Col BID
----------      -----------       -----------        -----------
address 1a      P000001           address 2b         P000002
address 2b      P000002           address 7g         P000007
address 3c      P000003           address 1a         P000001
address 4d      P000004           address 8h         P000008
address 5e      P000005           address 6f         P000006
address 6f      P000006           address 1a         P000001
                                  address 9i         P000009
```

What I've done so far is creating a new column containing all the addresses from both columns. Then I just remove the duplicates using the Remove Duplicates function to get the unique addresses. I am stuck at the ID part and going back to the original columns to assign the new IDs.

The IDs need to be in this format - P###### (# is the number)

I have over 100k addresses to go through. I am open to using Python or VB to accomplish this.

Thank you guys. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Excel are you running?

Comment: Does this have to be done by a script? I can help you make one it will just take a bit. If not I can explain how to do it manually.

Comment: @BradyK any which way will do - manual or script. Thanks!

Comment: [Openrefine](http://openrefine.org/) is what you are looking for. It will dedup ans cluster your addresses effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Code optimized. Run time reduced

Here is a VBA routine that will do that.  On my computer, it took about 6 seconds to process 220,000 addresses of which about 150,000 were unique.

This assumes your data starts in A1, and comprises a distinct region.

- Define Class object for cAdrKey with properties of Address and ID
- Read data into an array
- Add elements of array into a collection, as the Class object, using the Key property so as to prevent duplicates
- Add a unique ID to each address non-duplicated address
- Set up results array with the four columns
- Get the unique ID for each address from the collection object
- Write the results onto the worksheet

First define a Class (Insert/Class Module) and rename the module **cAdrKey**

Paste this code into the Class module:

==================================

```
Option Explicit
Private pAddr As String
Private pID As String

Public Property Get Addr() As String
    Addr = pAddr
End Property
Public Property Let Addr(Value As String)
    pAddr = Value
End Property

Public Property Get ID() As String
    ID = pID
End Property
Public Property Let ID(Value As String)
    pID = Value
End Property
```

===================================

Then, in a regular module, paste this code:

====================================

```
Option Explicit
Sub ProcessAddresses()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet
    Dim rSrc As Range, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim colAddr As Collection, cAK As cAdrKey
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
    Dim O As Object

'Set worksheets for Source and Results
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Set first cell for results
Set rRes = Range("F1")

'Get Source data
With wsSrc
    Set rSrc = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
End With
vSrc = rSrc

'Collect list of Unique Addresses
Set colAddr = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc)
    For J = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
        Set cAK = New cAdrKey
        With cAK
            .Addr = vSrc(I, J)
            .ID = Format(K, "\P000000")
            colAddr.Add cAK, CStr(.Addr)
            If Err.Number = 0 Then K = K + 1
            Err.Clear
        End With
    Next J
Next I
On Error GoTo 0        

'Generate Results
ReDim vRes(1 To UBound(vSrc), 1 To 4)
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc)
    vRes(I, 1) = vSrc(I, 1)
    vRes(I, 2) = colAddr(vSrc(I, 1)).ID
    vRes(I, 3) = vSrc(I, 2)
    vRes(I, 4) = colAddr(vSrc(I, 2)).ID
Next I

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes), UBound(vRes, 2))
rRes.EntireColumn.Clear
rRes = vRes
rRes.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

====================================

Comment: I tried the code, but I got "subscript out of range" error.

Comment: If you want to troubleshoot the code, I'll need more information.  What line was highlighted with the error?  Are your worksheets named the same as in the code? Is your data stored in the area the code expects?

Comment: @antsemot I made some changes in the code which have had the effect of reducing the runtime, on a two column sample of 110,000 rows (220,000 addresses), with about 150,000 unique addresses, down to about six seconds on my machine

Comment: @Ros Rosenfeld Oh. I used the wrong sheet. Will run this again and let you know.

Comment: @antsemot Be sure to use the modified code that is presently in my answer; not the code that you might have originally copied.  The only changes are in the regular module, the class module is unchanged.

Comment: thank you! I used this code for another file and it works fine! :)

Answer (score 0):

## Step 1:

Copy the two columns into one column together in a new location(could be a new sheet or an empty range on the same sheet.)

## Step 2:

Select this new range of cells and select `Remove Duplicates` from the `Data` tab in the ribbon.  Simply select `Continue with the Current Selection`, click `Remove Duplicates` then click `OK`.

## Step 3:

Beside the new, duplicate-free list put the unique ID's.

## Step 4:

Insert a column between columns A and B.

## Step 5:

Use a formula like: `=VLOOKUP(A2, "THE RANGE OF THE ADDRESSES AND ID's", 2, FALSE)` in Columns B and D.

## Step 6(Optional):

Copy and paste values over the `VLOOKUP` formulas and delete the unique address/ID table.

Comment: thanks for the steps. I am stuck at step 5 - some of the values are N/A.

Comment: oh okay got it. changed the range and got the IDs. Thanks!